# Metal shader way too dark

Tags: rendering

What am I doing wrong? I have tried twice with this specific pbr, it comes out super dark. Am I missing something?

I have tried to make completely serperate textures as well, with the same result. Is it the object, the lighting (everything else is lit fine)?

[image]

Comment: Your metallic map is collapsed, so I can't tell, is it set to non-color? Also, consider connecting your texture coordinate to it. Last thought is that your normal map strength may be too high (I find that <= 1 is good most of the time).

Comment: Metallic is set to linear, flat, repeat, single image, non-color. I also dropped my map strength with no changes either.

Comment: Could be flipped normals. In edit mode, select all > mesh > normals > recalculate outside. Other than that, it might have something to do with you using both bump and displacement, but I cant tell without seeing the file.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I only added bump after it wasn't working, and a tutorial had that step. Recalculating outside did not help, either. I believe it has to do with the file I downloaded for the model of the brace (it is an stl file) and I imported some bolts right now and the exact same nodes created the desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

pbr shaders need an environment to look more properly. It's one of the key parts in physical based rendering method.
Here is a metal shader under different environments:

[image: same shader, different environments]

to the left we have no environment (black), blender jungle in the middle and blender default room environment in the right.

A quick fix for this would be to add a good environment texture that matches your presentation of the area or comes close to it.
you can start looking for one here: https://hdrihaven.com/