# Inconsistent material effect with metalness

Tags: materials

[image]I created two objects, the first [a pipe] started life as a curve and then I "beveled" it using a disk and converted to mesh. The other [a sensor] started life as a disk and then I extruded it with a few times. Then I applied metalness workflow to each. When I render, the pipe looks lovely, but the sensor is completely "flat". What am I missing? [image]

[Edit] I deleted the material and reapplied, and now rendering in Cycles. Somehow the pipe is showing..... Almost like my sensor is inside out or something?
I'm happy to upload blender file but I dont know how to....

[Edit/Edit] Ok, so I trashed that model and started again. This time I drew it in the xz plane and used screw to rotate. And cool. The normals are now where they are supposed to be... I did have trouble filling in the "hole" in the middle. What I have below is a solid cylinder in the middle of a rotated curve and you can see that the screw modifier has lots of artifacts along the top, whereas the cylinder is just fine. Is there an easy way to fix that. [Or maybe this is a separate question]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your blend file, or at least upload screen shots of the shaders and wire frame of each object?  It looks like you're applying two different shaders, so there's probably a difference between them.  Also, it is possible that your sensor object has bad geometry.  Select it in edit mode and type shift-n to recompute normals to see if that helps.

Comment: shift-n did not fix it. I deleted the material completely and reapplied and it is doing something different now. Not different good.... but different. So yes I think the sensor has a bad geometry.

Comment: Aha. I went to edit mode, selected faces, then found overlay and clicked "face orientation" and my pipe is blue and the sensor is red !!

Comment: Alt N > Recalculate outside.

Comment: here is the link to upoad: https://blend-exchange.com/ just follow instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=k167PXDa" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/k167PXDa/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Metal shader way too dark](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190674/metal-shader-way-too-dark)

Comment: Hi @AllenSimpson, no, I tried but no help. I'm pretty sure the geometry got trashed somewhere along the line. It is easy enough to rebuild. I am thinking the trouble started by extruding from a disk as opposed to extruding from the face of a cylinder. Anyway, that is my next plan...

Comment: Hello and welcome,I highly recommended you to ask that second question as a separate one to get more answers

Comment: Will do. Thanks. Ok. Maybe first I should check previous answers :-)